# Copying files from one machine to another

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, network-share, documentation

I'm currently generating documentation on one machine, and publishing it to a web server using the following commands in a script:

```
net use "\\someShare" PASSWORD /user:username
del /S /Q "\\someShare"
xcopy /E /Y Documentation\html\* "\\someShare\"
```

However, it feels like a really bad idea to have a password as plain text in the script, so I'm looking for alternatives to my current solution. Ideas?

I definitely would appreciate a solution that uses some kind of access control, as many different people should be allowed to publish their own documentation to the web server, but not mess with each other's docs.

Comment: Have you considered using FTP?

Comment: Or a Wiki? or CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory for single sign on so that you don't have to supply a plain-text password in your script.

But maybe you don't want to or can't use AD. Well then, add the credentials to the Credential Manager in the Windows control panel.  Then just copy stuff over using UNC paths and forget all that drive mapping noise.

Granular access control you can do with or without Active Directory, it's just a matter of whether you want to use domain accounts or local accounts.  ACL your directories and shares however you want to give the desired access to whomever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this script is manually started and users can interact with the command prompt, why not remove the PASSWORD so it'll prompt for a password.

```
net use "\\someShare" /user:username
```